# Gerar array com as posições de substrings

Tags: php, array, string

Há alguma forma de eu pegar uma string, exemplo: "João foi bar ontem noite".
Gerar um array que armazene a posição de todos os " " dessa string.

Usarei isso para colocar nessas posições por exemplo, "no","de". Tendo assim : "João foi no bar ontem de noite".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque não usa o explode() na string e transforma toda frase em um array? Em seguida remonta a string com o novo texto?

```
<?php
// Example 1
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
```

Manual do explode http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php